# UITableView not deselecting?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a very simple tableview in a xib file with it's delegate and datasource hooked up to TestVC. TestVC is simple:

```
#import "TestVC.h"

@implementation TestVC

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *IDEN = @"IDEN";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IDEN];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:IDEN];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"called");
    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

When I click on a cell, it doesn't get deselected. I even put a log statement there to see if didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method is being called and it is.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

is the one you need